# Create Input Format of Elasticsearch using Flink Rich InputFormat

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink, flink-batch

We are using Elasticsearch 6.8.4 and Flink 1.0.18.

We have an index with 1 shard and 1 replica in elasticsearch and I want to create the custom input format to read and write data in elasticsearch using apache Flink dataset API with more than 1 input splits in order to achieve better performance. so is there any way I can achieve this requirement?

Note: Per document size is larger(almost 8mb) and I can read only 10 documents at a time because of size constraint and per reading request, we want to retrieve 500k records.

As per my understanding, no.of parallelism should be equal to number of shards/partitions of the data source. however, since we store only a small amount of data we have kept the number of shard as only 1 and we have a static data it gets increased very slightly per month.

Any help or example of source code will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to generate queries to ES that effectively partition your source data into relatively equal chunks. Then you can run your input source with a parallelism > 1, and have each sub-task read only part of the index data.